# Call a jQuery function once

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I'm trying to make a class method in JS where an action have to be repeated only once. The method is call in a loop, and I want it method to move a character once and stop. But the click event is repeated a lot, so the character move ~40 times,  and when I try with the jQuery "one()" it doesn't works, it's the same.

So that is my function (called in a permanent loop) :

```
Player.prototype.pushBox = function() {

    $(".box").click(function() { // The 'one()' doesn't resolve anything

        console.log('coucou'); // This is printing 40 times 

        for (var i = 0; i < boxArray.length; i++) {
            var box = boxArray[i];

            if (box.id == player.id + moveHorizontal) {
                $("#tile" + box.id).addClass('ground');
                box.x += boxSize;
                box.id += moveHorizontal;
                player.x += boxSize; // So this is called 40 times 
                player.id += moveHorizontal;
            }
        }
    });
 }
```

Comment: Escuse me, I'm not understanding what you are saying ?

Comment: Oh, I misread something, so I'm going to delete that previous comment.  You could make a flag that will exit the event handler early if it has already run once before.

Comment: It may be a solution, but this method have to be called other times, when there is a click on a box

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 40 objects with class "box" and the click event is triggered 40 times even if you use one()

```js
 $(".box").one('click', function() {
     console.log('sss');
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"><div class="box"><div class="box">click</div></div></div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g39dkn2t/1/

Comment: In fact, I've 3 objects box, and the condition can be good for only one of them.

Comment: @BaptisteMenard i mean you have incorrect markup somehow

Comment: @BaptisteMenard Can you show your markup or set up a fiddle?

Comment: I think that I found the problem : when I write the same code you wrote up there in my game loop, the console.log is repeated a lot of time per click. And my method is put in that game loop...

Comment: @BaptisteMenard if the code is in a loop the event is attached 40 times, that's the error.